# Select query for jsonb column with list in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jsonb

I have table with `jsonb` column.
I need to write a query to select all rows for which the errors column contains `LATEST_PERIOD_TOO_OLD`. But the examples I found only work if you have a key. But I do not have it. Classic `like` cannot be used for `jsonb` either

Table:

```sql
 id |                 errors                 
----+----------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | ["LATEST_PERIOD_TOO_OLD"]
  2 | ["LATEST_PERIOD_TOO_OLD", "DURATION_TOO_SMALL"]
  3 | null
```

Field in `Entity class`:

```kotlin
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "errors", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    var errors: Set<ValidationError>? = null,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@>` [contains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING) operator.

```sql
select * from the_table where errors @> '["LATEST_PERIOD_TOO_OLD"]';
```

Unrelated to the question but why don't you use a normalized data design?

Answer (score 0):

The sql query is :

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE jsonb_path_match(errors, '$[*] ? (exists(@ == "LATEST_PERIOD_TOO_OLD"))')
```